# Sync contact info based on email in three mySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need to INSERT firstname from table 1 into table 3, but email from table 1 needs to match email in table 2, then get the id of table 2 which matches the userid in table 3 and INSERTS in value with attributeid "4"
Table Setup -

```
Table #1: `hostusau_hostusac_emailcontacts`.`clients`
PID
firstname
lastname
email

Table #2: `hostusau_hostusac_emailcontacts`.`phplist_user_user_1`
id
email

Table #3: `hostusau_hostusac_emailcontacts`.`phplist_user_user_attribute_1`
attributeid
userid
value
```

This is my current query and doesn't seem to work as I am expecting.

```
 INSERT INTO phplist_user_user_attribute_1(attributeid,userid,value) SELECT
 '6',clients.PID,clients.firstname FROM clients JOIN phplist_user_user_1 ON
 clients.email = phplist_user_user_1.email
```